# Xamarin - Could not install package. Package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.

Tags: android, xamarin, altbeacon

[image: error output]

I have tried googling the errors and tried the solutions but have not worked thus far.

Comment: As the error states, you are using API 24 support library against Android 6.0, which uses API 23

Comment: @cricket_007 so all I have to do is install API24 in SDK manager and set the emulator to run android 7.0 and I should be good?

Comment: I am not sure. I don't use Xamarin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @cricket_007 mentioned, it is saying that you are trying to install this library which requires `MonoAndroid v6.0` at minimum. Thus this means that you need to ensure you are compiling against `API 23 or greater`. You can go to your Android Properties and set the `Compile using Android version` option to >= API 23.

[image]

Comment: I had to install some more package for API 23. It runs now, thanks all.